# How can i copy the lines, or words observed the numbers of rows?

Tags: excel, notepad++

How can i copy the lines, or words observed the numbers of rows?

1. one
2. two
3. three
4. four

I want copy lines 2-4. not lines 1-3. I want maintaining the structure of lines:

1. 2. two
2. 4. four

[image]

I'm using Excel or Notepad++

Answer (score 2):

Several other alternatives...

a) From the immediate window or VBA code:

```
 Range("a1,a3,a5").Select
 union(selection.offset(,3),selection).Select
 Selection.FillRight
```

b) Activate Autofilter then

- select just {uno,tre,cinque}.
- Select D1:D5 then hold down Ctrl and Select A1:A5
- From the menus choose *Home | Editing | Fill > FillRight*

Comment: +1 - That might work better with the new requirement to be able to do it with any combination of row.

Answer (score 0):

If the original data is in column A in Excel, you can put a formula in column B (example for B1):

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(A1),2) = 1, A1, "")
```

and drag it down.

You can then copy / paste special / values into a new column if you want to get rid of the formulae.

Comment: mmm..the formula give me an error,look http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/622/errorformula.png

Comment: Just tested on excel 2003 & 2010 and it works... Maybe try to remove the spaces? What version of Excel are you using? Do you copy the formula in B1 (or another column, but not in column A)?

Comment: @user1391247 That's weird... Maybe try to tack it down: try to insert `=ROW(A1)` in B1 => it should return 1. Then try to insert `=MOD(1,2)` in B1 => it should return 1.

Comment: OR you might need to use `;` instead of `,` in the formula depending on your regional settings...

Comment: Can you write the complete formulas please? Still gives me errors, perhaps wrong to write. However, the first formula I've tested on hotmail.com but I do not understand why it does not work copy as plain text

Comment: What do you mean "tested on hotmail.com"? Are you using Microsoft Excel or not?

Comment: My version of Excel is in english

Comment: If u go to hotmail.com u can use an online version of Excel (2010). Yes, I'm using a local 2007 version of Excel..

Comment: I don't have Excel 2007 installed and I can't reproduce what you see in my version so I am not sure what to do... Have you tried the 2 more simple formulae (`=ROW(A1)` and `=MOD(1,2)`) to see if they work?

Comment: Thanks, now formula it works..but can i solve this problem for random lines? Look here please http://nathan3000.altervista.org/Test_Vari/excel_copy_lines.htm

Comment: @user1391247 Nice animation! Your new question is fairly different. I don't think that what you are asking is possible directly, you will need to use a tweak. For example, you could add some `X` in column B for the lines you wish to copy and in column C: `=IF(B1="X";A1;"")`.

Comment: Yes..it works..thanks!..but in Notepad is impossible replicate the structure? because i work always with bookmark (marked line)

Comment: @user1391247 I don't use Notepad++ so can't help on that one.